# Can I early-release an autorelease object?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

i.e. would cause the object to be released immediately and not have to be released by the pool if I did this?

```
[[NSArray arrayWithCapacity:100] release];
```

Can't find a clear explanation in the docs about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would likely crash when the object would normally be autoreleased. `autorelease` means "delayed release", so it will be released: just later. Since the object won't exist later as you are manually releasing it, you will likely crash due to the runtime sending the `-release` message to your now-deallocated object.

Edit: Note that if you `-retain` objects that come autoreleased, you do have to `-release` them: you are taking ownership.

Comment: Let's say that (for whatever reason) I *do* want it to get released right now. Is "[[obj retain] release]" a valid option?

Comment: Not really. In that case, you should wrap the whole thing in @autoreleasepool { } to create and destroy the pool the autorelease is happening in.

Comment: agree, wrap the whole thing in @autoreleasepool

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is stupid now, and that I shouldn't be releasing something I don't own.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the object to go into the auto-release pool, you can do a manual `alloc` and `initWithCapabity`.  If you do that, you'll have to manually `release` it at some point.